# Use WebRTC camera in AR-session ios

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, augmented-reality, realitykit

already implemented webRTc video call in ios. I want to add AR to a video call. eg: suppose user draw aline in his local view remote user can see it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on an open source app that does exactly this using Agora's network instead of webRTC. It works pretty well as a proof of concept.

Two devices connect to the same channel, one as a host and one as the support. When the support draws on the screen it adds a line in 3D for the other.

This link goes straight to the latest commit, as it's not all merged to the default branch yet:

https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/AR-Remote-Support/tree/5a0b3a3c7c32b05e0548831bd80007ea624f8851

Comment: This only works in SceneKit though, some of the open source libraries I'm using would need to be changed for RealityKit